# jQuery dataTables overwrites the SQL-statement ORDER BY

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery dataTables and I'm overwhelmed.

But now using it in a shopsystem I have a problem.

The SQL-statement in my sourcecode ends with
ORDER BY orders_id DESC

When I open the shop backend the sorting order is set to 
ORDER BY orders_id ASC by jQuery dataTables.

Do I need a plugin or is there an attribute for jquery dataTables to keep the sorting?

Greetz
Ron

Comment: Show your output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example in their api docs. http://datatables.net/api

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

     // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
     oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
   } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the following property of DataTable plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        // [0, 'asc'] - 0 represents the first column and 'asc' represents the ascending sort order
        // [1, 'desc'] - 1 represents the second column and 'desc' represents the decending sort order
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'desc']]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

```
  "order": [[9, "asc"]], //9 represents the column number
```

});